# How to input special character in cmd?

Tags: shell, cmd

I have written a c program that retrieves arguments from the command line under Windows. One of the arguments is a regular expression. So I need to retrieve special characters such as "( , .", etc., but cmd.exe treats "(" as a special character.

How could I input these special character?

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put the arguments in quotes:

```
myprogram.exe "(this is some text, with special characters.)"
```

Though I wouldn't assume that parentheses cause problems *unless* you are using blocks for conditional statements or loops in a batch file. The usual array of characters that are treated specially by the shell and need quoting or escaping are:

```
& | > < ^
```

If you use those in your regular expression, then you need quotes, or escape those characters:

```
myprogram "(.*)|[a-f]+"
myprogram (.*)^|[a-f]+
```

(`^` is the *escape character* which causes the following character to be not interpreted by the shell but instead used literally)

Comment: I assume that `^` also needs escaping.  You should add that to your list.

Answer (score 11):

You can generally prefix any character with `^` to turn off its special nature. For example:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Pax>echo No ^<redirection^> here and can also do ^
More? multi-line, ^(parentheses^) and ^^ itself
No <redirection> here and can also do multi-line, (parentheses) and ^ itself

C:\Documents and Settings\Pax>
```

*That's a caret followed by an ENTER after the word `do`*.

Comment: Note that you don't need to escape parentheses unless you are using this in an conditional or loop block such as `if foo==bar ( echo ^(foo^) )`

Comment: @joey - is it still possible to escape it? Not escaping that might lead to problems, if someone unmindfully does a copy/paste...