# Escaping special characters in cmd

Tags: escaping, cmd

I have a Windows .bat script in which I try to run a command with password in parameter. The password I want to be able to use is `~!@#$%^&*()_+|-=\][{}';:"/.>?,<`.

From what I've read [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), I should escape `^&|\<>` with `^`. From what I assume, I should escape `"` with `\"`.

This gives me something like that:

```
runme.exe /password:"~!@#$%^^^&*()_+^|-=^\][{}';:\"/.^>?,^<"
```

But it doesn't work - my target app responds with logon failure.

How should I escape all these characters to be able to hardcode the password in my batch (ignoring the security issues by now)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741546/how-to-input-special-character-in-cmd

Comment: So you're suggesting `/password:~!@#$%^^^&*()_+^|-=\][{}';:"/.^>?,^<`? Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: % is special, %% seems to escape it.

Comment: Still no luck: `/password:~!@#$%%^^^&*()_+^|-=^\][{}';:"/.^>?,^<`

Comment: Just to record sake, I had to escape `;` with `^` otherwise it will term `;` as end of command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Double the quote in the password and make sure the complete password is enclosed in quotes as well:

```
runme.exe /password:"~!@#$%%^^^&*()_+^|-=\][{}';:""/.>?,<"
```

Comment: That worked: `/password:"~!@#$%%^&*()_+|-=\][{}';:""/.>?,<"` (no additional `^` inside the quotes). Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have % in your password - try %% instead.
More here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, but if `runme.exe`'s argument parser requires quotes as string encapsulators for passwords, the it's not going to work. If you need to have a quote in your password, then runme.exe needs to provide a way to escape it!

```
runme.exe /password:~!@#$%%^^^&*()_+^|-=\][{}';:"/.>?,<
```

Comment: Still no luck. What do you mean by providing a way to escape? I have no control over `runme.exe` unfortunately. Are you suggesting that `runme.exe` may not be able to support passwords with `"`?