# Escaping password with characters sequence "^%" in cmd.exe

Tags: cmd, passwords, escaping

I'm try to install my Windows-service:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" /user="DOMAIN\Administrator" /password="Password^%" "ServiceName.exe"
```

But my service does not start. Exit with error:

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1069:
The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

because the password is incorrect.

I try use change password as like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296162/escaping-special-characters-in-cmd), i.e. I run:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" /user="DOMAIN\Administrator" /password="Password^%%" "ServiceName.exe"
```

but it did not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping special characters in cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296162/escaping-special-characters-in-cmd). Double the `%` percent sign only in a batch script, don't do that from `cmd` window.

Comment: Try `"/password=Password^%"`or `"/password=Password%"` if your  password is exactly `Password^%` or `Password%`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks! It's work. My clear password is **"Password^%"** and escaping of password with argument helped. i.e. **"/password=Password^%"**.

Answer (score 0):

Need to escape password with a argument as:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" /user="DOMAIN\Administrator" "/password=Password^%" "ServiceName.exe"
```

Comment: What if your password contains a `"`?