# Cannot pass the '^' as command line argument in windows cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I want to pass the ^ character as a command-line argument. But, it is treated as a blank. How can I pass this character in command-line in windows.

Comment: It needs to be escaped, but escaping in cmd is a nightmare ... try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032953/which-symbol-is-escape-character-in-cmd#:~:text=Unfortunately%20CMD%20uses%20different%20escape,a%20in%20('type%20file. Also, https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html.  You might need to have two carets `^^`

Comment: Why do you want this? What's the command and what is the complete list of parameters you want to pass?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping)