# Runing .jar with argument that contains char ">" and some strange things happen

Tags: java, jar, zxing

I have a .jar file, calling it like this:

```
java -jar qr-0.1.jar message=])rsfkoekfoe023k20f9k0fk3oi43jf
```

The code generates an pdf417 qr image, and drops it at c:/tmp, all outputs are displayed in the console.

The problem is when I put the character > in the message, like so:

```
java -jar qr-0.1.jar message=])>rsfkoekfoe023k20f9k0fk3oi43jf
```

This creates an random file next to the jar with the console output inside, and the pdf417 qr image encodes only the first two characters :/

The thing is, when I debug, the message with the char > works fine, it breaks only when i create the jar file.

This is how i set arguments in code:

```
for(String arg : args){
        String[] argument = arg.split("=");
        keyword = argument[0];
        if(argument.length>1){
            value = argument[1];
        }

        if(keyword.equals(KEY_MESSAGE)){
            message = value;
        }
        else if(keyword.equals(KEY_WIDTH)){
            w = Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
        else if(keyword.equals(KEY_HEIGHT)){
            h = Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
        else if(keyword.equals(KEY_FILENAME)){
            fileName = value;
        }
        else if(keyword.equals(KEY_FILEPATH)){
            filePath = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just use backslash to escape this special `<` character

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to input special character in cmd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741546/how-to-input-special-character-in-cmd)

Comment: I put the whole message inside " " and no backslash, and it works. It takes the whole message now.

Comment: this is also a variant

Comment: `>` redirects the output. This has nothing to do with java, but with the shell/command line interpreter that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it like this:

```
java -jar qr-0.1.jar message="])>rsfkoekfoe023k20f9k0fk3oi43jf"
```

Or by escaping special characters using backslash